# Animate dynamic height of View on mount/unmount

Tags: react-native, animation, layout

I've been working to animate some cards that toggle open and closed. The contents are dynamic, so I can't set a fixed height.

Ideally the height should start at zero, then we learn the intended full height of the item by using the setLayout method of the view.

Then a standard Animated.spring or Timing event can animate the height value.

Here's a snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@ahartzog/animated-dynamic-height

Answer (score 0):

https://tutorialscapital.com/react-native-dynamically-expand-collapse-slidedown-slideup-view-using-layoutanimation-tutorial/

This tutorial explained it - have to use the LayoutAnimation API instead of directly trying to animate it myself.